# Video frame capture

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture a frame from a video in android and save it or use it in any way in the application?

Comment: Where does the video come from - local file, network or camera capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have official APIs to do so. You may end up in [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), using third-party video codec [library](http://ffmpeg.org/) to decode a frame. Keep in mind that different video formats and codecs have different licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the Camera.previewCallback you would implement the onPreviewFrame where you will receive the raw byte data for a single frame. This method will be called at your fps.

Answer (score 0):

We have released our FREE SDK that will allow any application to record an OpenGL commands on Adnroid thus having very low overhead. Later the trace file with the commands can be converted to high resolution MPEG and posted to YouTube, we can even upscale the resolution to full 1080p since we have the commands and "in cloud renderer".

More info on the SDK: www.seemegaming.com